# Ideal triangulation of hyperbolic 3-manifold with generic mapping class group

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, hyperbolic-geometry, 3-manifolds, mapping-class-groups, triangulations

I am from physics background so I apologize in advance if my question is trivial.

Kojima proves for every finite group $G$, there is a hyperbolic 3-manifold such that its mapping class group equals $G$ ([here](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82773183.pdf)). I wonder if it is possible to work out an ideal triangulation for the manifold he constructs.

Some examples of hyperbolic 3-manifold with explicit ideal triangulation and with some simple non-trivial mapping class group would also be very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hyperbolic manifolds considered by Kojima are closed, so do not admit ideal triangulations in the "usual sense".  (They admit "partially flat, spun, ideal triangulations" but I am not sure that is what you are interested in.)

It is an open question whether or not every finite volume cusped hyperbolic three-manifold admits an ideal triangulation (with all tetrahedra positively oriented).

Finally, the standard example of a manifold admitting an ideal triangulation (with all tetrahedra positively oriented) is the figure-eight knot complement.  This manifold, called m004 in the snappy census, has mapping class group isomorphic to $D_4$. Taking normal covers of m004 gives examples with more symmetry.

See the book [Hyperbolic knot theory](https://bookstore.ams.org/cdn-1598077516917/gsm-209), by Jessica Purcell, as reference on this material.